# How to generate PDF from table with page break properly

Tags: php, html, css, loops, dompdf

I have PHP project running with laravel. The idea is very basic: I just want to generate PDF from database with DOM PDF. I already included CSS inside the view to set the display. It was doing fine with only one page shown. But when I generate more than one page(page-break), the display is messed up. Seems like the data was overlapping one another. Im not sure whats going on here, but I think the problem is in my styling CSS. Please help!

PS. I set my PDF page orientation: landscape and paper: f4

[image]

```
<style>
.page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;

}

.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: none;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: none;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
<body>
<?php

foreach($query as $query){

    ?>
//to split page left and right  
<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">

    <h2>{{$query->full_name}}</h2>
    <p>Some text.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <div class="centered">

    <h2>{{$query->full_name}}</h2>
    <p>Some text here too</p>
  </div>
</div>

//page break
<div class="page-break"></div>

<?php }?>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to add this code in your blade file

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. i found a solution please check below code. For the DOM PDF the html format arrangement is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@page { margin: 20px 50px 50px; 
        @top-center {
            content: element(header);
        }
        @bottom-left {
            content: element(footer);
        }
 } 
  div.header {
        display: block;
         top:0; left:0; right:0;
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
    }
    div.footer {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        position: running(footer);
        width:100%;
        clear:both;
    }
    div.content {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class='header'>Header</div>
   <div class='footer'>Footer</div> 
   <div class='content'>Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this solution is works for you.